# Manipulate Longitudinal Data, Combine 2 Col & Transpose to Wide

Tags: sas

I need to manipulate longitudinal data to be able to use in a logistic regression.

Currently the data is:

```
ID  Period Smoke
1     1      1
1     2      1
1     3      1
2     1      0
2     2      1
2     3      1 
3     1      1
3     2      1
3     3      0
```

But i need to manipulate it into this form:

```
ID    Period1Smoke   Period2Smoke    Period3Smoke
1           1              1              1
2           0              1              1
3           1              0              0
```

So essentially, I need to somehow combine Period & Smoke, and then transpose to wide format by ID. (Also I'll need to do this across several var & ~5,000 individuals.)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into proc transpose?

Answer (score 0):

In proc transpose, ID is in the BY statement to specify that we need just one observation in the output dataset for each distinct value of ID. Period in ID statement indicates that new variables are to be created in the output dataset for each distinct value of Period. The variable to transpose (Smoke) is specified in the VAR statement. Use prefix= and suffix= options to control how the new variables should be named.

For an introduction to proc transpose syntax, refer to this [this](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/060-2009.pdf) paper.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want (drop=_name_) prefix=Period suffix=Smoke;
    by ID;
    id Period;
    var Smoke;
run;
```

Comment: please add an explanation of your code to your answer